# Returning two SUM results in foreach loop from one mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am trying to get the results of two different SUMs in one query because I am using a foreach to display the results. Actually the second result needs to be a count of how many records in the database points.PID = 3. The only way I can get the $total SUM and $conts to display properly for each result is to use a ForEach loop, but I'm not sure it is possible to have two SUM results returned, especially since the second SUM/count "conts" has a WHERE clause.

The code below works great for getting total, but as soon as I add:

```
SUM(points.PID WHERE points.PID = 3) AS conts
```

I get no results. Of course it should be count and not SUM anyway. Is this possible? I can't figure out the approach. If I need a second query for conts, how would the foreach know to match those results with the correct record in the loop?

```
$results = $dbh->prepare("select 
  wp_users.ID,
  wp_users.display_name,
  points.ID,
  points.PID,
 SUM(points.PID) AS total,
 SUM(points.PID WHERE points.PID = 3) AS conts
FROM points
LEFT JOIN wp_users ON points.ID=wp_users.ID
 GROUP BY points.ID ORDER BY total DESC
 LIMIT 5");
$results->execute();
$row = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

//Display Results

```
foreach ($row as $all) {
echo "<td>$all7[total]</td>";
echo "<td>$all7[conts]</td>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `SUM(IF(points.PID = 3, 1, 0)) AS conts`

Comment: I tried replacing my second SUM with your code and I just get a blank page/no results. I like the approach but don't quite get it. Of course, it isn't working anyway. Thanks for trying

Comment: If you're getting a blank screen then you're getting an error. Make sure you have your errors turned on `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` this will show PHP errors. To see mysql errors try `print_r($dbh->errorInfo());`

Comment: I only meant blank results. The table doesn't show up bc there are not results, but the rest of the web page displays fine.

Comment: Maybe i'm not understanding the purpose of the sum though. you want to sum PID only if it's equal to 3. So you're end result would be a mulitple of 3? `3 + 3 + 3 + ...` ?

Comment: Actually just the cont column results do not display. Yes, the cont variable is supposed to be a sum of all the PID records that equal 3. The total variable which works fine, adds up all the PID numbers regardless of what number they are and gives the total for each user.

Comment: Do you need the sum? or the count of the ones that equal 3. like if you have 4 PIDs equal to 3 do you want to return the number 4 or 12?

Comment: Great question--and I can't believe I didn't clarify. I want the COUNT…so I want it to say 4

Comment: Actually…I get results, but they are not right. There should be just 1 result that equals 3 for the first user. 19 total points are right, but just 1 record has 3 points for that user, and yet I get 8 with your latest code for conts

Comment: I changed it back to SUM, give that a check to make sure it works but that should be the way to do it. When you use COUNT(table.id) it counts the different table.id's up. When you use sum, it's adding the numbers together. In this case, we tell it to add 1 every time PID = 3 and add 0 when it's not. IF( expression , true value , false value)

Comment: That's it! Excellent skills on your part! thanks for understanding my needs here so well too and for explaining what is going on in the working code. I didn't know we could do an IF inside of SUM. cool stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you perform the sum(points.PID) where points.PID = 3 as a subquery, you should be able to accomplish this. Your query would end up being something like this:

```
SELECT  
  wp_users.ID,
  wp_users.display_name,
  points.ID,
  points.PID,
  SUM(points.PID) AS total,
  cnts.tot as conts
FROM points
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      SUM(points.PID) as tot,
      ID
    FROM
      points
  ) cnts 
    ON cnts.ID = points.ID
  LEFT JOIN wp_users
    ON points.ID = wp_users.ID
GROUP BY points.ID 
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: where would I work in the where points.PID =3 condition in this approach, considering this condition only applies to the second SUM for conts?